# Multi-Core Haskell on Windows

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing, multicore

I've been reading a number of [tutorials](http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/blog/2007/11/29) [on](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_5_steps) Haskell. However, I have not been able to get the compiled application to run on a multicore (I have an Intel Quad Core) on **windows (32 bit)**.

I have tried a number of things:

- [ghc -O2 --make A.hs -threaded](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_5_steps)
- [./real-par +RTS -N2](http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/blog/2007/11/29)
- [./real-par +RTS -N4](http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/blog/2007/11/29)

But no luck.

The compiled application runs 100% on one core only.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Monad
import Text.Printf

fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = l `pseq` r `pseq` l+r
    where
    l = fib (n-1)
    r = fib (n-2)

main = forM_ [0..350] $ \i ->
        printf "n=%d => %d\n" i (fib i)
```

Comment: Could you add the code you're trying to run?

Comment: Are you running 32 or 64 bit?  It probably matters.

Comment: updated question for both commmets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If vili is correct (I can't test as I don't own any MS boxes), it might be related to [this bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2868)

Answer (score 6):

Using par instead of pseq seems to fix it.

Comment: are you running windows? Because that didn't do anything for me